# Слово "куда" (как местоимение)

Tags: местоимение

В каких случаях слово "куда" является местоимением?

Answer (score 1):

**Все ответы (или почти все) можно найти в толковом словаре** [куда | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x). Куда - это **местоименное наречие**, но оно может выполнять функцию  союзного слова в сложноподчиненных предложениях и даже бывает частицей. Всё это расписано в словарной статье.

**КУДА.** I. **местоим. нареч**. 1. Обозначает вопрос: в какое место? в каком направлении? К. теперь идти? К. ты едешь летом? **II.** **союзн. сл**. 1. Присоединяет придаточные предложения места. Поедем, к. захотим. Уехал туда, к. давно собирался. Взглянул туда, к. указывали ему рукой. 2. Присоединяет придаточные дополнительные. Хочу спросить, к. мы идём? 3. Присоединяет придаточные определительные. Городок, к. мы приехали, был тих и уютен. 4. Употр. в придаточных уступительных в сочетании с частицами "ни", "бы... ни". К. ни посмотришь, всюду следы разрушений. * Куда бы нас ни бросила судьбина, И счастие куда б ни повело, Всё те же мы (Пушкин). **III. частица.** 1. Разг. (в сочет. с прил. или нареч. в сравнит. ст.).

Comment: *Куда - это местоименное наречие, но оно может выполнять функцию союзного слова в сложноподчиненных предложениях и даже бывает частицей.* Как это "местоименное наречие" может быть частицей или союзом? Это три *непересекающихся* альтернативы для классификации слова куда как части речи. Слово может принадлежать к разным частям речи, но одна часть речи никак не может быть другой.  Или Вы что-то свое под такой формулировкой понимаете?

Comment: Существует переход одной части речи в  другую, это же обычное явление в языке, например: первый день - первый (лучший) ученик. В словаре: ПЕРВЫЙ,  I. числ. порядк. к Один .II. прил. 1. Первоначальный,  2. Лучший ; отличный. Но на первом месте стоит основное (исходное) значение многозначного слова.

Comment: Существует некое явление, которое какому-то терминологическому по недоразумение называют "переходом". Но даже в этом случае требуется чтобы слово на каком-то историческом этапе было одной  частью речи, а потом приобрело признаки другой. Субстантивация прилагательных, например. А здесь-то какие основания называть фактические омонимы "переходом"? Пример с "первым" вообще не к селу ни к городу. "Первый" во всех значениях прилагательное или порядковое числительное, что в общем-то одно и тоже.  Если, конечно, это не имя собственное в примерах типа "первый сказал" - в значении начальник, "главный".

Comment: В словаре "первый" называют и порядковым числительным,  и прилагательным. Да и для многих слов в словарной статье указываются разные значения слов и разные части речи, к которым эти значения  относятся.  Слово развивает новое значение и относится уже к другой части речи. Как  назвать это явление?

Comment: *В словаре "первый" называют и порядковым числительным, и прилагательным* - но уж наверное не называют, что одно "перешло" в другое. Я не возражаю, что это слово принадлежит двум частям речи. Но во-первых, это бесконечно близкие части, а во-вторых, тут нет того, что можно читать "переходом". Я Вам про Фоу, а Вы мне про Ерему.

Comment: Да,  есть что-то похожее. А вот если вернуться к первому высказыванию  "куда - это местоименное наречие, но оно может выполнять функцию союзного слова в сложноподчиненных предложениях", то  что здесь неправильно? Ведь союзное слово - это не служебная часть речи, как союз,  а всего лишь синтаксическая функция, не правда ли?  А какая это часть речи? Местоименное наречие в роли союзного слова или, может быть,  относительное местоимение - как-то в словаре про это не чётко прописано.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех, когда не частица и не союз, - местоимение (или местоименное наречие).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x